# Should one give a bounty to anyone to prevent it from expiring?

Tags: discussion, bounty

[This bounty will expire in 24h](https://askubuntu.com/questions/428512/my-graphic-drivers-are-gone). The answers do not solve the issue. Should I pick any answer or the answer of the user who put more effort or not?

I was thinking to award it to **terdon**  because he kept updating his answer trying to help me and kept commenting. But his answer does not solve the problem.

In short, should I reward the effort or not? As it stands, I still have a problem with no solutions.

Answer (score 2):

Bounty is very similar to a cash reward. If you think the answerer resolved your problem or gave you a perfect alternative or even if it resolves most of your problems or it says that the problem you have does not have a solution(possible), you may consider rewarding the answerer.

It is completely at your disposal to reward the answerer. However, don't do it for the sake of doing it, knowing you have lost it so its of no use throwing it away.

Answer (score 1):

### No

If you do, it will probably be considered as a trade of points.The thinking that "Anyway, I'm loosing the points, let someone else get them" isn't that good.

The best option would be to let the bounty go away.If you don't get your answer for some more time, you may want to consider offering another bounty weeks/months later.

About the efforts, if someone else gets his/hers solution from terdon's answer, the person would(probably) upvote it as useful.

Also note that half of the bounty amount is transfered to the highest voted answer if it has more than 2 votes.